# Histograms in Chart::gnuplot ( perl ) Is it possible?

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I know gnuplot can handle histograms.  I know perl is effectively doing a pass through when using Chart::gnuplot.  And when I set plot type to histograms I don't get an error.  But it does keep complaining that there are too many columns.  Which is a bit baffling since I am only setting data for the y axis.

Has anyone ever plotted a histogram using Chart::gnuplot straight up?  Example code?

Comment: Please add the code you're having trouble with. This will help us with what is a practically impossible question to answer, as written.

Comment: Hey alex there is no example code, since there is no supported method for chart::gnuplot to create a histogram as a graph type.  It's a limitation of chat::gnuplot.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no functionality to create histograms in the perl module Chart::gnuplot.  You can regex a plot template and generate from a system / exec call.

Answer (score 0):

This URL does not help?

```
http://chartgnuplot.sourceforge.net/
```

here are examples - maybe for your problem too.

Comment: Not in there.  Pretty sure it's unsupported.  I've taken to creating the gnuplot scripts via perl as well as the data sets then making system calls to get gnuplot to run directly.  Not sure if that is the best method, but it seems to be a commonly accepted approach.

Answer (score 0):

To plot histogram by Chart::Gnuplot, the "using" option of the dataSet object need to be set as:

```
using => "2:xticlabels(1)"
```

Besides, please don't forgot to set the style as "histograms". E.g.

```
my $ds = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    xdata => [qw(A B C)],
    ydata => [1, 2, 3],
    using => "2:xticlabels(1)",
    style => "histograms",
);
```